# Filter out ISPs from Whois results

Tags: network, ip, isp, blacklist, whois

I was wondering if there is any efficient way or any service (free or not) that may help me in order to identify companies behind IP addresses.

I figured out that in some cases **Whois** may be really helpful for that. 
Unfortunately, in a lot of cases the result given by Whois is an ISP (which I'm not surprised of).

Is there any way (service, tool) to get the result only if it is a "real" company ("real" company meaning *not being an ISP*)?

Is there any "*blacklist*" (regularly updated) of all the ISPs Whois may be returning, so that I could compare the result given with that blacklist to filter out the results being ISPs?

Once again my only goal is to have the information (company owning the IP address) only when it's available, without having to manually check if the Whois result is an ISP or not.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: At some level, [domain privacy](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/21084/how-hard-is-to-be-the-anonymous-owner-of-a-website) is something you will not be able to get around.

Comment: While there might be somewhere a relation to information security the way the question is currently asked does not show this relation. Therefore I've marked it as off-topic.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich where I am supposed to ask it then?

Comment: @TheoBabilon: I'm not sure that there is a stackexchange site where this is on-topic. Alternatively there might actually be an information security problem behind the question you ask, only that you don't ask the question currently in a way which shows this problem. Maybe (but only maybe) this would get clear if you explain why you want to get company but not ISP data from whois in the first place, i.e. what problem do you really want to solve.